# Spring Cron verification

Tags: java, spring, cron

Could you verify that all my jobs are correctly configured ?  I'm not sure for year task

```
//Every Hour
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * * ")
public void taskHour() {}

//Every Day
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * *")
public void taskDay() {}

//EveryMonth
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 1 * *")
public void taskMonth() {}

//Every Year
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 1 1 *")
public void taskYear() {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The pattern is a list of six single space-separated fields:
>   representing second, minute, hour, day, month, weekday. Month and
>   weekday names can be given as the first three letters of the English
>   names.
>
> Example patterns:
>
> ```
> "0 0 * * * *" = the top of every hour of every day.
> "*/10 * * * * *" = every ten seconds.
> "0 0 8-10 * * *" = 8, 9 and 10 o'clock of every day.
> "0 0 6,19 * * *" = 6:00 AM and 7:00 PM every day.
> "0 0/30 8-10 * * *" = 8:00, 8:30, 9:00, 9:30, 10:00 and 10:30 every day.
> "0 0 9-17 * * MON-FRI" = on the hour nine-to-five weekdays
> "0 0 0 25 12 ?" = every Christmas Day at midnight
> ```

Quote from the [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html)

So analyzing your code

```
//Every Hour
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * * ") 
public void taskHour() {}
```

the top of every hour of every day. - OK

```
//Every Day
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * *") 
public void taskDay() {}
```

the top of every day. - OK

```
//EveryMonth
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 1 * *")
public void taskMonth() {}
```

It is scheduled for the first day of the month. - OK

```
//Every Year
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 1 1 *")
public void taskYear() {}
```

It is scheduled for the first day of the january so it will be done once a year. - OK

So your code satisfies your requirements.